# Angular-leaflet-directive syntax Error: Token '{' invalid key at column 2 of the expression

Tags: mean.io, angular-leaflet-directive

I have issue when use angular-leaflet-directive to create multiple map.

I have list City  and i want to use ng-reapeat to display many map.

this is code

```
<div ng-repeat="(key,city) in listCity" class="panel panel-info col-md-2" style=" height: 25%;">
      <div class="panel-heading">{{city.name}}</div>
      <div class="panel-body" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;">
          <leaflet style="width: 100%; height: 90%;" center="{{city.place_id}}"></leaflet>
      </div>
    </div>
```

it alert error `Syntax Error: Token '{' invalid key at column 2 of the expression [{{city.place_id}}] starting at [{city.place_id}}]`. 
when i test by change 'center' with other string then It haven't error.

Please help me fix it.

thank you so much !!!!!!!

Comment: Could you set up a Plunk or something to provide us with some more information, or at least provide sample data of what's contained in `listCity`?

Comment: this is sample data of list City{
     'name' : 'West Jakarta City',
     'lat' : '-6.168872',
     'lng' : '106.756572',
     'place_id' : 'ChIJ7x9CSLj3aS4RmvSqYhrWPhg'
    }

Comment: angular.extend($scope,{
                ChIJ7x9CSLj3aS4RmvSqYhrWPhg: { // location ACEH
                    lat: -6.168872,
                    lng: 106.756572,
                    zoom: 12,
                    place_id: 'ChIJB0vJuDb0aS4RlHPzGrFt85A'
                }
               })

Comment: A basic Plunk (or similar) would be best, to have a sample that 'can' work.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [example in the docs](http://tombatossals.github.io/angular-leaflet-directive/#!/examples/center), you must provide a `lat`, a `lng` and a `zoom` in your center property.

So try something like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="city in listCity" class="panel panel-info col-md-2" style=" height: 25%;">
    <div class="panel-heading">{{city.name}}</div>
    <div class="panel-body" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;">
        <leaflet style="width: 100%; height: 90%;" center="{ lat: city.lat, lng: city.lng, zoom: 10 }"></leaflet>
    </div>
</div>
```

I assume your `listCity` is an Array.